# Discord.js | split a message

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I'm pretty new to the development world, I wanted to practice doing JS, and I learned that Discord bots could be done in this language, I found it cool to practice.

My problem: I want to separate the command from the rest of the message. I managed to separate the command from a word, but when I enter several words, it does not work. This is what it does:

> (!Command HELLO" will send "Command + Hello", but "!command  HELLO HI" will not work)

```js
const PREFIX = "!";
bot.on('message', function(message) {
 if(message.content[0] === PREFIX) {
  let splitMessage = message.content.split(" ");
  if(splitMessage[0] === '!command') {
   if(splitMessage.length === 2) {
    message.channel.send('Command + ' + splitMessage[1]);
   }
  }
 }
});
```

Thanks

Comment: Use indexOf() to find the first occurence of whitespace and substring() to grab everything after the first whitespace

Comment: It is not clear what should be the result for command HELLO HI. You should send two commands? Or a command with two parameters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I stated in the comment:

```
    const PREFIX = "!";
    bot.on('message', function(message) {
        if(message.content[0] === PREFIX) {
            let command = message.content.substring(message.content.indexOf(" ") + 1, message.content.length);
            message.channel.send('Command + ' + command);
        }
    });
```

Comment: hey, how can send the message when the split is done?

Comment: Yes, it works, but I don't know the variable that content the message :(

Comment: I updated my answer, just concatenate the command string variable to your .send() string.

Comment: TypeError: message.indexOf is not a function

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to use the property content of message, see revised answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
 splitMessage[1]
```

that takes the second word from the splitted array. So with `Command! Hello world` it will be `Hello`. You might want to take everything after the first element from the split Message like so:

```
splitMessage.slice(1)
```

that returns `["Hello", "World"]`, so you just need to join it back to a string

```
 .join(" ")
```

---

How i would do that:

```
  const [command, ...args] = message.content.split(" ");

  switch(command){
    case "!Command":
       message.channel.send('Command + ' + args.join(" "));
    break;
    //....
  }
```

Comment: Thank you, I understood how it worked. As for the code, I can not make it work :(